# Exporting a figure

Tags: matlab, parameters, parameter-passing, figure

I came across [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) program for exporting a figure. I just want to ask, what should I pass to the program if I want to export a figure of mine to some image (i.e; .jpg), as I couldn't figure out what to pass as a parameter.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that you can use the safe way here at least. For example `export_fig('handle', hfig, 'filename', 'master_yoda', '-format', 'png')`, but I am not completely sure.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in command [`print`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) is used to export a figure to an image. Like so:

```
 plot(rand(4))
 print('-djpeg', 'myplot.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

patrik's suggestion probably refers to [this ME file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig). (Which is great, by the way)

A native MATLAB solution would be

```
saveas(<handle of the figure>,<file path with .jpg at the end>)
```

This is what I have used for a long time and it works (e.g., `saveas(h,'/figures/automatic/myfig.jpg')`); but it is very possible that `print` or something else is better suited for whatever reason.